# Как называются люди, регулярно следящие за новыми технологиями и их развитием?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Как назвать человека, который **смотрит вперёд, открыт новым знаниям и применяет эти знания в жизни?**

Comment: Подходит "передовой", но так обычно не говорят о людях.

Comment: Промышленные шпионы :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Новатор, инноватор, пионер, первопроходец, креативщик.

Comment: Следящие за (созданными другими) технологиями, усваивиющие и применяющие знания ничего нового не создают, это в лучшем случае проектировщики, но никак не первопроходцы и т. п.

Comment: Человек, который смотрит вперёд, ОТКРЫТ новым знаниям, и ПРИМЕНЯЕТ эти знания в жизни. Это не ученые, они не делают открытий, но готовы применять эти открытия на практике.

Comment: Открыт новым знанием = всегда учится, применяет технологии по назначению = работает - не более того. Содавать новое - значит изобретать, обладая к этому природными способностями.

Comment: Изобретатель работает в своей конкретной области, но есть люди, которые следят за ВСЕМИ новыми изобретениями и применяют новые знания в  жизни. Именно о таких людях был вопрос.

Comment: Но под предложенное определение подходят не новаторы и не первопроходцы с пионерами (это творческие люди), а скорее, _потребители_ новых технологий (люди, которые стремятся "быть в курсе" создаваемого другими и **применять** это), если не "следящие какую-нибудь науку" маниловы и любители последних моделей айфонов.:)

Answer (score 0):

Всегда таких людей называли прогрессивными. Сейчас, наверно, больше подходит "продвинутый", если это не специалист в компьютерных технологиях.